# Add logo to left side of Back button in navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to add a logo to the very left side of my navigation bar. I still want to display the Back button and the title of the page, but the logo must be fixed to the left side before the Back button.

I tried adding the logo as a Bar Button Item, but this removes the Back button.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `UIBarButtonItem` as the `leftBarButtonItem` then you can also set the property

```
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

This will allow you to have two buttons without disrupting the back button. However it won't be on the far left, that space is reserved for the back button. If you want to go against Apple's design guidelines and the logo is more important the standard iOS navigation, you'll need to do something custom.

You could use the `leftBarButtonItems` property on `UINavigationItem` to set multiple items in your own order. One of those could be a logo and another a custom back button that you set to call `navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`